# Do black holes have a well-defined temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation), black holes emit Hawking radiation that corresponds to the spectrum a black body would emit at a temperature inversely proportional the mass of said black hole. Since the mass of a black hole is well defined (I believe), does this mean that the temperature of a black hole is also well defined?

Since the horizon of a black hole is an extended region in space, it means that the information of the temperature at some point in the horizon cannot travel faster than light to the whole horizon, I do not know how it would be possible for a black hole to have a well defined single temperature.

I am thus wondering if black hole have a well defined temperature, and if so, how is that possible that, for any observer, the temperature in the whole horizon space is the same?

Comment: Why do you think that the information of the temperature at some point in the horizon must travel faster than light to the whole horizon? Wouldn't your argument apply to the surface of a regular star? Having said that, in a view of any external observer, remote, hovering, or falling (as long as still external), information cannot travel along the horizon at all, because the speed of light at the horizon is zero.

Comment: @safesphere not only would it apply to any star, it would apply to any *object* :)

Comment: The case of a star or any object is quite different. They do not need to have a well defined temperature to begin with, so any tiny region of their surface can be at a different temperature than other ones. Black hole however, apparently need to have a well defined temperature since it must equal an expression that depends on the inverse of their mass

Comment: Take an aluminium rod. If its temperature had to be equal to an expression inversely proportional to its mass, not only would its thermal conductivity need to be infinite, but heat propagation would need to happen at an infinite speed, which is of course impossible. My question is how do black hole can have such a property, if they really have it?

Comment: Why are you assuming that two parts of an object - or, indeed, two separate objects - need to violate causality to have the same temperature? I and an alien in the Andromeda galaxy can both make tea at 100 C without ever having to have communicated at all.

Comment: @AlNejati If heat propagation has a finite speed, then the Al rod will not have a uniform temperature (and thus no well defined temperature, and thus not in thermodynamics equilibrium) if a perturbation is applied at a precise region of the rod. But for Al of course it doesn't matter as the temperature needs not to be connected to its mass, unlike the black hole case.

Comment: And how would you 'perturb' the temperature at some point on the black hole?

Comment: @AlNejati if the horizon has a spherical or ellipsoidal shape, then placing a star near it would make the interaction asymmetric. The overall temperature would decrease in time, but the information that the black hole is absorbing matter through some part of the horizon should not be transmitted to the whole horizon instantly, and as far as I understand, this would be the only way for the black hole to have a well definite temperature.

Comment: The short answer is that changing the structure of spacetime in such a dramatic way would violate the assumptions under which black hole temperature was originally defined. The long answer requires a bit more physics and would probably be better served as its own separate question post.